# Ajax jQuery Multiple Step Form instead of reloading div, just append new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, submit

I wonder if it's possible to do this multistep form on one single page, so not reloading the div with the content received from the php file but append it right below..

This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function(){
var ln = $('#submit').val();
var id = $('#id').val();

var data = 'submit='+ln;
  $.ajax({

  type: 'GET',
  url  : 'step.php',
  dataType : 'html',
  data : data,
  success :  function(data)
       {
      $('#reg-form').fadeOut(500).hide(function()
      {
       $('.result').fadeIn(500).show(function()
       {
        $('.result'+id).append(data);
       });
      });

       }

  });
       return false;

});
```

Also I tried to use different divs, with incremental id's to put every content in it's own div. The Problem is, I'm only getting the "second" step, so it's not going through the whole formular.

I guess it's because the form of the first page is still there and all have the same id.. Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: _"I guess it's because the form of the first page is still there and all have the same id.."_ `data` includes `html` containing duplicate `id`?

Comment: the form id is not unique, yes.. I don't know how to write the code above with different id's for different forms, so the function is run when any of the forms is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. Change the duplicate `id` at `html` source or using `javascript`

```
success :  function(data) {
      // change duplicate `reg-form` `id` to value
      // corresponding to `.length` of elements having `id`
      // containing `"reg-form"`
      $(data).filter("#reg-form")
      .attr("id", "reg-form-" + $("[id*='reg-form']").length); 
      $("#reg-form").fadeOut(500).hide(function() {
       $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function() {
        $(".result" + id).append(data);
       });
      });
}
```